# retrieving just the title of a webpage in python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have more than 5000 webpages i want the titles of all of them. In my project i am using the BeautifulSoup html parser like this.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(url).read())
soup('title')[0].string
```

But its taking lots of time. Just for the title of a webpage i am reading the entire file and building the parse tree(I thought this is the reason for delay, correct me if i am wrong).

Is there in any other simple way to do this in python.

Comment: Have you tried lxml.html? Its faster than bs

Answer (score 3):

It would certainly be faster if you just used a simple regular expression, `BeautifulSoup` is pretty slow. You could do something like:

```
import re
regex = re.compile('<title>(.*?)</title>', re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
regex.search(string_to_search).group(1)
```

Comment: You should limit the wildcard ``.*?`` and ``|re.DOTALL``, so ``.`` matches newline.

Comment: Couldn't you read the webpage in an iterative manner, stopping as soon as the title was found? It seems that one could reliably skip almost all of the content of any site when only the title is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a regular expression to do it, but that might break if you get a badly formatted page. That'd be something like this:

```
import re
titleRE = re.compile("<title>(.+?)</title>")
title = titleRE.search(s).group(1)
```

Comment: Oh I didn't realize the compiled regexp had a `search` method. That's handy, I've been passing it around.

Answer (score 1):

You could even use the simple [string methods](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods):

```
html = '<html> lots of crap <title>Title</title> even more crap </html>'
start = html.find('<title>') + 7 # Add length of <title> tag
end = html.find('</title>', start)
title = html[start:end]
```

However, this only guarantees that `<title>` is found before `</title>` in the page. Not that it is in the `<head>` section or anything.

Also, you should validate your assumption that it actually *is* the BeautifulSoup parsing that comsumes the lion's share of the time. (My guess is that `open(url).read()` for 5,000 resources takes quite some time, too. This you will not eliminate, no matter *how* you "parse" the HTML.)

Comment: Couldn't you read the webpage in an iterative manner, stopping as soon as the title was found? It seems that one could reliably skip almost all of the content of any site when only the title is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
>> hearders = {'headers':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0'}
>>> n = requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108778/', headers=hearders)
>>> al = n.text
>>> al[al.find('<title>') + 7 : al.find('</title>')]
u'Friends (TV Series 1994\u20132004) - IMDb'
```