# Scrape title by only downloading relevant part of webpage

Tags: python, html, performance, web-scraping

I would like to scrape just the title of a webpage using Python. I need to do this for thousands of sites so it has to be fast. I've seen previous questions like [retrieving just the title of a webpage in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960087/retrieving-just-the-title-of-a-webpage-in-python), but all of the ones I've found download the entire page before retrieving the title, which seems highly inefficient as most often the title is contained within the first few lines of HTML.

Is it possible to download only the parts of the webpage until the title has been found?

I've tried the following, but `page.readline()` downloads the entire page.

```
import urllib2
print("Looking up {}".format(link))
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
       'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
       'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
       'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
       'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
       'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
req = urllib2.Request(link, headers=hdr)
page = urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=10)
content = ''
while '</title>' not in content:
    content = content + page.readline()
```

**-- Edit --**

Note that my current solution makes use of BeautifulSoup constrained to only process the title so the only place I can optimize is likely to not read in the entire page.

```
title_selector = SoupStrainer('title')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml", parse_only=title_selector)
title = soup.title.string.strip()
```

**-- Edit 2 --**

I've found that BeautifulSoup itself splits the content into multiple strings in the self.current_data 
 variable ([see this function in bs4](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/__init__.py#L337)), but I'm unsure how to modify the code to basically stop reading all remaining content after the title has been found. One issue could be that redirects should still work.

**-- Edit 3 --**

So here's an example. I have a link www.xyz.com/abc and I have to follow this through any redirects (almost all of my links use a bit.ly kind of link shortening). I'm interested in both the title and domain that occurs after any redirections.

**-- Edit 4 --**

Thanks a lot for all of your assistance! The answer by Kul-Tigin works very well and has been accepted. I'll keep the bounty until it runs out though to see if a better answer comes up (as shown by e.g. a time measurement comparison).

**-- Edit 5 --**

For anyone interested: I've timed the accepted answer to be roughly twice as fast as my existing solution using BeautifulSoup4.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can defer downloading the entire response body by enabling stream mode of `requests`.

> [Requests 2.14.2 documentation - Advanced Usage](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow)
>
> By default, when you make a request, the body of the response is
>   downloaded immediately. You can override this behaviour and defer
>   downloading the response body until you access the **`Response.content`**
>   attribute with the `stream` parameter:
>
> ...
>
> If you set `stream` to `True` when making a request, Requests cannot release the connection back to the pool unless you consume all the data or call **`Response.close`**. 
>   This can lead to inefficiency with connections. If you find yourself partially reading request bodies (or not reading them at all) while using `stream=True`, you should consider using contextlib.closing ([documented here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing))

So, with this method, you can read the response chunk by chunk until you encounter the title tag. Since the redirects will be handled by the library you'll be ready to go.

Here's an error-prone code tested with **Python 2.7.10** and **3.6.0**:

```
try:
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
except ImportError:
    from html.parser import HTMLParser

import requests, re
from contextlib import closing

CHUNKSIZE = 1024
retitle = re.compile("<title[^>]*>(.*?)</title>", re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
buffer = ""
htmlp = HTMLParser()
with closing(requests.get("http://example.com/abc", stream=True)) as res:
    for chunk in res.iter_content(chunk_size=CHUNKSIZE, decode_unicode=True):
        buffer = "".join([buffer, chunk])
        match = retitle.search(buffer)
        if match:
            print(htmlp.unescape(match.group(1)))
            break
```

Comment: This seems to work very well! What do you mean by that it's error-prone? Perhaps a feasible solution is just to run this on all the links. For those where this approach fails, run the standard slow approach. However, what errors do you expect and how should I catch them?

Comment: For the links I've tested (New York Times and Stack Overflow) it finds the title after resp. 7 and 2 chunks of size 64. Loading the entire page is resp. 417 and 872 chunks. Amazing!

Comment: How does the streaming work? Should I be aware of not setting a too low chunk size?

Comment: @pir Nothing special. Casual exceptions, request time-outs, ssl issues etc. As you can see there's no error handling, that's what I meant.

Comment: @pir 1024 to 2048 is OK for a tag like <title> that expected on top of the response.

Comment: Ok, thanks! It does seem to have some problems though. Can you see why it doesn't detect e.g. this link? The title is pretty clear in the source.  https://www.bloomberg.com/news/features/2017-01-27/jared-kushner-s-felon-father-brought-two-fellow-inmates-into-company

Comment: Seems to be more of an issue with the regex than the request as I can find it using `buffer.index('title')`. The regex seems quite simple though..

Comment: Are you using Python 3? I'm using Python 2. I get a `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)` error.

Comment: Ah, nevermind! It's due to printing the title. Thanks again!

Comment: For anyone interested: I've timed the accepted answer to be roughly twice as fast as my existing solution that was using BeautifulSoup4.

Comment: It seems to not always follow any link forwarding? For instance, it seems to get stuck on a lot of bit.ly links.

Comment: @pir stuck how? An exception? If so, what's error details, a stack trace for example? Most importantly, what's the bit.ly link you're having trouble? There are a lot of possibilities so need more details to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Ah.. I think I found the problem. A link like https:// + t.co + /bvYsgn56Nl (separated due to SO posting issue) links to http://linkis.com/conservatives4palin.com/uGXam, which is actually a link to http://conservatives4palin.com/2015/11/robert-tracinski-the-climate-change-inquisition-begins.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter .. what a mess. It has nothing to do with your method.

Comment: It seems that `HTMLParser` was deprecated in python3.9, now `import html` and then `html.parser.unescape()`
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=975395

Answer (score 4):

> **Question**: ... the only place I can optimize is likely to not read in the entire page.

This does not read the entire page.

> **Note**: Unicode `.decode()` will `raise Exception` if you cut a Unicode sequence in the middle. Using `.decode(errors='ignore')` remove those sequences.

For instance:

```
import re
try:
    # PY3
    from urllib import request
except:
    import urllib2 as request

for url in ['http://www.python.org/', 'http://www.google.com', 'http://www.bit.ly']:
    f = request.urlopen(url)
    re_obj = re.compile(r'.*(<head.*<title.*?>(.*)</title>.*</head>)',re.DOTALL)
    Found = False
    data = ''
    while True:
        b_data = f.read(4096)
        if not b_data: break

        data += b_data.decode(errors='ignore')
        match = re_obj.match(data)
        if match:
            Found = True
            title = match.groups()[1]
            print('title={}'.format(title))
            break

    f.close()
```

> **Output**:
>   title=Welcome to Python.org
>   title=Google
>   title=Bitly | URL Shortener and Link Management Platform

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2 and 2.7.9***

Comment: Very interesting, thanks!  An easy way to test redirection is to use bit.ly to shorten any link. Running this in Python 2.7 using `from six.moves import urllib` gives me a bunch of decoding exceptions. Only `http://www.python.org/` works for me. Any way this could be made more robust?

Comment: @pir: Added **Python 2.7** support and removed decoding exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

You're scraping webpages using standard REST requests and I'm not aware of any request that only returns the title, so I don't think it's possible.

I know this doesn't necessarily help get the title only, but I usually use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for any web scraping. It's much easier. Here's an example.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.msn.com"]

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    print "Title with tags: %s" % soup.title
    print "Title: %s" % soup.title.text
    print
```

Output:

```
Title with tags: <title>Google</title>
Title: Google

Title with tags: <title>MSN.com - Hotmail, Outlook, Skype, Bing, Latest News, Photos &amp; Videos</title>
Title: MSN.com - Hotmail, Outlook, Skype, Bing, Latest News, Photos & Videos
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm also using BeautifulSoup currently, but it's too slow :/

Comment: Assuming that the REST request interface sends the data back in a streaming fashion, couldn't one just cut the connection after the first few lines was received? Is the information encoded somehow that would make this difficult?

Comment: @pir In theory you could. You'll have to go down to the socket level and write code to read data from the socket and disconnect when you deem appropriate. You may end up spending more time writing this code than just reading the whole page using a higher level library though as you may need to handle errors, DNS, proxies, redirects, etc. Another thing to think about is that the <title> tag is not required and is optional. Thought it's normally towards the beginning of the response, I believe it can also be at more towards the end.

Answer (score 2):

the kind of thing you want i don't think can be done, since the way the web is set up, you get the response for a request before anything is parsed. there isn't usually a streaming "if encounter `<title>` then stop giving me data" flag. if there is id love to see it, but there is something that may be able to help you. keep in mind, not all sites respect this. so some sites will force you to download the entire page source before you can act on it. but a lot of them will allow you to specify a range header. so in a requests example:

```
import requests

targeturl = "http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Blarg&page=2"
rangeheader = {"Range": "bytes=0-150"}

response = requests.get(targeturl, headers=rangeheader)

response.text
```

and you get

```
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#'
```

now of course here's the problems with this
what if you specify a range that is too short to get the title of the page?
whats a good range to aim for? (combination of speed and assurance of accuracy)
what happens if the page doesn't respect Range? (most of the time you just get the whole response you would have without it.)

i don't know if this might help you? i hope so. but i've done similar things to only get file headers for download checking.

EDIT4:

so i thought of another kind of hacky thing that might help. nearly every page has a 404 page not found page. we might be able to use this to our advantage. instead of requesting the regular page. request something like this.

```
http://www.urbandictionary.com/nothing.php
```

the general page will have tons of information, links, data. but the 404 page is nothing more than a message, and (in this case) a video. and usually there is no video. just some text.

but you also notice that the title still appears here. so perhaps we can just request something we know does not exist on any page like.

```
X5ijsuUJSoisjHJFk948.php
```

and get a 404 for each page. that way you only download a very small and minimalistic page. nothing more. which will significantly reduce the amount of information you download. thus increasing speed and efficiency.

heres the problem with this method: you need to check somehow if the page does not supply its own version of the 404. most pages have it because it looks good with the site. and its standard practice to include one. but not all of them do. make sure to handle this case.

but i think that could be something worth trying out. over the course of thousands of sites, it would save many ms of download time for each html.

EDIT5:

so as we talked about, since you are interested in urls that redirect. we might make use of an http head reqeust. which wont get the site content. just the headers. so in this case:

```
response = requests.head('http://myshortenedurl.com/5b2su2')
```

replace my shortenedurl with tunyurl to follow along.

```
>>>response
<Response [301]>
```

nice so we know this redirects to something.

```
>>>response.headers['Location']
'http://stackoverflow.com'
```

now we know where the url redirects to without actually following it or downloading any page source. now we can apply any of the other techniques previously discussed.

Heres an example, using requests and lxml modules and using the 404 page idea. (be aware, i have to replace bit.ly with bit'ly so stack overflow doesnt get mad.)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

links = ['http://bit'ly/MW2qgH',
         'http://bit'ly/1x0885j',
         'http://bit'ly/IFHzvO',
         'http://bit'ly/1PwR9xM']

for link in links:

    response = '<Response [301]>'
    redirect = ''

    while response == '<Response [301]>':
        response = requests.head(link)
        try:
            redirect = response.headers['Location']
        except Exception as e:
            pass

    fakepage = redirect + 'X5ijsuUJSoisjHJFk948.php'

    scrapetarget = requests.get(fakepage)
    tree = fromstring(scrapetarget.text)
    print(tree.findtext('.//title'))
```

so here we get the 404 pages, and it will follow any number of redirects. now heres the output from this:

```
Urban Dictionary error
Page Not Found - Stack Overflow
Error 404 (Not Found)!!1
Kijiji: Page Not Found
```

so as you can see we did indeed get out titles. but we see some problems with the method. namely some titles add things, and some just dont have a good title at all. and thats the issue with that method. we could however try the range method too. benefits of that would be the title would be correct, but sometimes we might miss it, and sometimes we have to download the whole pagesource to get it. increasing required time.

Also credit to [alecxe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) for this part of my quick and dirty script

```
tree = fromstring(scrapetarget.text)
print(tree.findtext('.//title'))
```

for an example with the range method. in the loop for link in links: change the code after the try catch statement to this:

```
rangeheader = {"Range": "bytes=0-500"}

scrapetargetsection = requests.get(redirect, headers=rangeheader)
tree = fromstring(scrapetargetsection.text)
print(tree.findtext('.//title'))
```

output is:

```
None
Stack Overflow
Google
Kijiji: Free Classifieds in...
```

here we see urban dictionary has no title or ive missed it in the bytes returned. in any of these methods there are tradeoffs. the only way to get close to total accuracy would be to download the entire source for each page i think.

Comment: Thanks! What if I were to simplify the problem to only get the domain (e.g. www.cnn.com)? I would still have to allow for redirects.

Comment: im not sure what you mean, the things you are after, namely `<title>` can only be achieved if you already have the domains you wish to scrape. im not sure what you would want to do with only domain names? however i did think of a hack that might help you better. see answer edit.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure you understand my problem correctly. I have a link www.xyz.com/abc and I have to follow this through any redirects (almost all of my links use a bit.ly kind of link shortening). So I wouldn't be able to modify the link to a 404 page because then I wouldn't be redirected. I'm interested in both the title and redirection that happens after the redirections, but perhaps domain would do.

Comment: ah, in this case the maybe you want to use a http head request. see edit 5 for this.

Answer (score 2):

using urllib you can set the Range header to request a certain range of bytes, but there are some consequences:

- it depends on the server to honor the request
- you assume that data you're looking for is within desired range (however you can make another request using different range header to get next bytes - i.e. download first 300 bytes and get another 300 only if you can't find title within first result - 2 requests of 300 bytes are still much cheaper than whole document)
- (edit) - to avoid situations when title tag splits between two ranged requests, make your ranges overlapped, see 'range_header_overlapped' function in my [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44286982/4387299)

  import urllib

  req = urllib.request.Request('http://www.python.org/')

  req.headers['Range']='bytes=%s-%s' % (0, 300)

  f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

  ## just to verify if server accepted our range:

  content_range=f.headers.get('Content-Range')

  print(content_range)

Answer (score 0):

my code also solves cases when title tag is splitted between chunks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue May 30 04:21:26 2017
====================
@author: s
"""

import requests
from string import lower
from html.parser import HTMLParser

#proxies = { 'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' }
urls = ['http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/p/learning-opencv-functions-step-by-step.html',
        'http://www.robindavid.fr/opencv-tutorial/chapter2-filters-and-arithmetic.html',
        'http://blog.iank.org/playing-capitals-with-opencv-and-python.html',
        'http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html',
        'http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.exposure.html',
        'http://apprize.info/programming/opencv/8.html',
        'http://opencvexamples.blogspot.com/2013/09/find-contour.html',
        'http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html',
        'https://github.com/ArunJayan/OpenCV-Python/blob/master/resize.py']

class TitleParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.match = False
        self.title = ''
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attributes):
        self.match = True if tag == 'title' else False
    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.match:
            self.title = data
            self.match = False

def valid_content( url, proxies=None ):
    valid = [ 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
              'text/html',
              'application/xhtml+xml',
              'application/xhtml',
              'application/xml',
              'text/xml' ]
    r = requests.head(url, proxies=proxies)
    our_type = lower(r.headers.get('Content-Type'))
    if not our_type in valid:
        print('unknown content-type: {} at URL:{}'.format(our_type, url))
        return False
    return our_type in valid

def range_header_overlapped( chunksize, seg_num=0, overlap=50 ):
    """
    generate overlapping ranges
    (to solve cases when title tag splits between them)

    seg_num: segment number we want, 0 based
    overlap: number of overlaping bytes, defaults to 50
    """
    start = chunksize * seg_num
    end = chunksize * (seg_num + 1)
    if seg_num:
        overlap = overlap * seg_num
        start -= overlap
        end -= overlap
    return {'Range': 'bytes={}-{}'.format( start, end )}

def get_title_from_url(url, proxies=None, chunksize=300, max_chunks=5):
    if not valid_content(url, proxies=proxies):
        return False
    current_chunk = 0
    myparser = TitleParser()
    while current_chunk <= max_chunks:
        headers = range_header_overlapped( chunksize, current_chunk )
        headers['Accept-Encoding'] = 'deflate'
        # quick fix, as my locally hosted Apache/2.4.25 kept raising
        # ContentDecodingError when using "Content-Encoding: gzip"
        # ContentDecodingError: ('Received response with content-encoding: gzip, but failed to decode it.', 
        #                  error('Error -3 while decompressing: incorrect header check',))
        r = requests.get( url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies )
        myparser.feed(r.content)
        if myparser.title:
            return myparser.title
        current_chunk += 1
    print('title tag not found within {} chunks ({}b each) at {}'.format(current_chunk-1, chunksize, url))
    return False
```