# Go through to original URL on social media management websites

Tags: python, regex, hyperlink, web-scraping

I'm doing web scraping as part of an academic project, where it's important that all links are followed through to the actual content. Annoyingly, there are some important error cases with "social media management" sites, where users post their links to detect who clicks on them.

For instance, consider [this link on linkis.com](http://linkis.com/conservatives4palin.com/uGXam), which links to http:// + bit.ly + /1P1xh9J (separated link due to SO posting restrictions), which in turn links to [http://conservatives4palin.com](http://conservatives4palin.com/2015/11/robert-tracinski-the-climate-change-inquisition-begins.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter). The issue arises as the original link at [linkis.com](http://linkis.com/conservatives4palin.com/uGXam) does not automatically redirect forward. Instead, the user has to click the cross in the top right corner to go to the original URL.

Furthermore, there seems to be different variations (see e.g. [linkis.com link 2](http://linkis.com/paper.li/gsoberon/jozY2), where the cross is at the bottom left of the website). These are the only two variations I've found, but there might be more. Note that I'm using a web scraper very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44184743/1452257). The functionality to go through to the actual link does not need to be stable/functioning over time as this is a one-time academic project.

How do I automatically go on to the original URL? Would the best approach be to design a regex that finds the relevant link?

Comment: No time to write an answer but looking for "unshorten URL python" might give you hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common architecture that the website follows is that it shows the website as an iframe. The sample code runs for both the cases.

In order to get the final URL you can do something like this:

```
import requests                                                                                                                                                                                        
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                                                                                                          

urls = ["http://linkis.com/conservatives4palin.com/uGXam", "http://linkis.com/paper.li/gsoberon/jozY2"]                                                                                                
response_data = []                                                                                                                                                                                     

for url in urls:                                                                                                                                                                                       
    response = requests.get(url)                                                                                                                                                                       
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')                                                                                                                                                 
    short_url = soup.find("iframe", {"id": "source_site"})['src']                                                                                                                                      
    response_data.append(requests.get(short_url).url)                                                                                                                                                  

print(response_data)
```

Comment: This seems more robust. Have you tried this? If it works consistenly I'll gladly give you the bounty.

Comment: I tried it on a few random links. You can plug it in with the code you've written. See if it works.

Comment: Do you know if any sites use the same code for other types of referrals? For instance, I wouldn't want to catch embedded videos etc. I only need to catch times, where the entire page is embedded from somewhere else.

Comment: You can give it a try on stumbleupon. You'll need to modify it to match their xpath though.

Comment: It doesn't work for another social media site, paper.li: http://paper.li/GreenFraud/1402893935?edition_id=7a57b7d0-8ade-11e5-852b-0cc47a0d15fd#/ Can you give me advice on how to make it work for this as well?

Answer (score 2):

In many cases, you will have to use browser automation to scrape web pages that generate their content using javascript, scraping the html returned by the a get request will not yield the result you want, you have two options here :

- Try to get your way around all the additional javascript requests to get the content you want which can be very time consuming  .
- Use browser automation, which lets you open a real browser and automates its tasks, you can use **Selenium** for that.

I have been developing bots and scrapers for years now, and unless the webpage you are requesting does not rely heavily on javascript, you should use something like selenium.

Here is some code to get you started with selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

#Create a chrome browser instance, other drivers are also available
driver = webdriver.Chrome()     

#Request a page
driver.get('http://linkis.com/conservatives4palin.com/uGXam')

#Select elements on the page and trigger events
#Selenium supports also xpath and css selectors
#Clicks the tag with the given id
driver.find_elements_by_id('some_id').click()
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you expand on why "scraping the html returned by the a get request will not yield the result you want"?

Comment: In most cases the complete HTML is not loaded when you request the page, instead additional XHR or javascript requests are made by the browser after the initial loading to render the full page, you can see this using any browser under developer tools -> networks,(in chrome you can press f12), the first response after opening a webpage is what you generally get when using requests.get,and you can observe how many more requests are made after that...

Comment: Okay., thanks. Why can't requests just grab the last request? How can the servers tell it apart from Selenium?

Comment: The server generally can't(in most case at least ..), you have to understand the process. with a real browser when you request a page, the scripts in the result will get executed, and when they get executed, they may do additional requests, with requests.get however, the scripts will still be downloaded, but that's about it, they are basically just a text, you must use a real browser to execute these scripts, or do it the hard way, check all the additional requests made after the initial loading then try mocking them, which can be often more difficult than it seems

Answer (score 1):

According to the two websites that you given, i think you may try the following code to get the original url for they all hidden in a part of javascript(the main scraper code i am using is from the question that you post):

```html
try:
    from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
except ImportError:
    from html.parser import HTMLParser

import requests, re
from contextlib import closing

CHUNKSIZE = 1024
reurl = re.compile("\"longUrl\":\"(.*?)\"")
buffer = ""
htmlp = HTMLParser()
with closing(requests.get("http://linkis.com/conservatives4palin.com/uGXam", stream=True)) as res:
    for chunk in res.iter_content(chunk_size=CHUNKSIZE, decode_unicode=True):
        buffer = "".join([buffer, chunk])
        match = reurl.search(buffer)
        if match:
            print(htmlp.unescape(match.group(1)).replace('\\',''))
            break
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work, import statements missing and even after adding them, still not working

Comment: I add the import statements.It seems work in my environment.what did you mean not working?Is there any code error occur or just can't get the link out ?

Answer (score 0):

say you're able to grab the href attribute/value:

```
s = 'href="/url/go/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F1P1xh9J"'
```

then you need to do the following:

```
import urllib.parse
s=s.partition('http')
s=s[1]+urllib.parse.unquote(s[2][0:-1])
s=urllib.parse.unquote(s)
```

and s will now be a string of the original bit-ly link!

Answer (score -1):

try the following code:

```
import requests

url = 'http://'+'bit.ly'+'/1P1xh9J'
realsite = requests.get(url)
print(realsite.url)
```

it prints the desired output:

```
http://conservatives4palin.com/2015/11/robert-tracinski-the-climate-change-inquisition-begins.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter
```